# Autoloading models

Tags: php, oop, autoload

I'm building an MVC framework and I was thinking that most of the classes used in the making of an application are models. So since I know that every model is inside a folder I could just use the native `__autoload()` function to implement a "feature" (that obliviously you can enable and disable as well) that automatically loads a model (Lazy programming).

Is it good or should I discard this idea? If the latter: why?

Comment: Is this PHP? Might help if you tag it as such.

Comment: I wouldn't think of doing any OOP in PHP without using __autoload or the SPL equivalent.  That's why they exist.

Comment: *Another* PHP-based MVC framework?

Comment: @MartinBean Mine. I'd use it only. No need of another CodeIgniter...

Comment: +1 for Martin. Even if it's for your own use, are _none_ of the existing frameworks suitable?

Comment: @halfer They are full of things useless for me. So I just built my own one that makes what I want it to do. Nothing else. It's lighter and use a code that I know what does it do. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Fair enough, if you're sure. But this may be a case of "re-inventing the wheel" :-). Using existing frameworks gets you the benefit of hundreds of bug fixes and testing. I should know - I work for a company that uses a home-grown PHP ORM, and every now and then I have to fix a core bug, rather than concentrate on the task at hand.

Comment: Yes I can get it. But those framework are full of line of codes. It's reasonably to have thousands of possible bug that grow exponentially at every line. I just have few, simple to check, probably bug-free, self written, trusted lines. And everything just works fine. :)

Comment: I was all for writing my own framework, but when I went self-employed and my time became money, using pre-built frameworks like Zend and CakePHP really sped up development for me once I got out of the mindset of, "They're superfluous" to, "I don't have to develop something as and when it's needed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building a PHP framework, it might be worth looking into the [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) for autoloading. I'm afraid I don't know much about it, but I believe a number of substantial frameworks and libraries have agreed to abide by it for interoperability. I believe that would include Symfony2, Propel2 and the next major version of Zend Framework.

Comment: Heh, no problems. "Abide" means to accept something; "inter-operable" means to work together (i.e. several libraries can all use the same auto-loading approach).

Comment: (Google translate) Se si sta costruendo un framework PHP, potrebbe essere utile esaminare il livello PSR-0 per caricamento automatico. Ho paura, non so molto, ma credo che un numero consistente di quadri e biblioteche hanno deciso di rispettarlo per l'interoperabilità. Credo che dovrebbe includere Symfony2, Propel2 e la prossima versione di Zend Framework.

Comment: PS: "abide = rispettarlo = to respect" is not a good translation. Also "framework = quadri = picture" and "libraries = librerie = bookshop"...

Comment: Heh, complain to Google then ;-). Yes, use PSR-0.

Comment: @halfer Wait. You might have misunderstood the point of my question. I know it's good to use __autoload() for classes. (If I'm not wrong I'd say that exists a specific pattern for that called Lazy programming). I wanted to know if using __autoload() is good for models in the MVC pattern.

Comment: I can't think that autoloading would be bad for anything, tbh. It is used (afaik) by all the PHP MVC frameworks for very good reason -  it cuts down on having to add load code, and better still improves speed (since a class that is not used saves an include op).

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with relying on the `__autoload()` function, as long as you have a consistent naming scheme.

In fact, it's often better to use autoloading - it stops you from including classes "just in case" you use them.